# Replacing elements with value is not the same

Tags: matlab, variables, precision, numeric, floating-point-precision

I do:

```
T = inv([1.0 0.956 0.621; 1.0 -0.272 -0.647; 1.0 -1.106 1.703]);
```

obtaining:

```
T =

0.2989    0.5870    0.1140
0.5959   -0.2744   -0.3216
0.2115   -0.5229    0.3114
```

if I do

```
 T(1,1)==0.2989
```

i obtain

```
ans =

 0
```

same for other elements.
why this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are not equal. Its just a display artefact. To see this:

```
fprintf('%.8f\n', T(1,1))
```

will give you

```
0.29893602
```

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB stores more digits than you usually see. The 0.2989 is actually 0.298936021293776 (and even that is not the end of the story).
Try your code and add

```
format long
T(1,1)
```

but still,

```
T(1,1) == 0.298936021293776
ans =
 0
```

So try

```
T(1,1) - 0.298936021293776
```

You just don't see all the digits. `T(1,1)` is what it is supposed to be.

Comment: how can I view all the digits??

Comment: I don't really know. But - why would you want to see all digits? If you want to check for equality, check if the two numbers are within some tolerance from each other.

Comment: I need to replicate the same behavior without call inv function (so i need just the numbers to use in a product... I resolve with fprintf('%.55f\n', T(1,1)) XD

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous to test floating point numbers for exact equality. Per default, MATLAB uses 64 bits to store a floating point value, and some values such as `0.1` cannot even exactly be represented by an arbitrary number of bits. `T(1,1)` is not exactly `0.2989`, which you can see when printing the value with a greater precision:

```
>> T = inv([1.0 0.956 0.621; 1.0 -0.272 -0.647; 1.0 -1.106 1.703]) 
T =
    0.2989    0.5870    0.1140
    0.5959   -0.2744   -0.3216
    0.2115   -0.5229    0.3114
>> fprintf('%1.10f\n', T(1,1))
0.2989360213
```

This is why `T(1,1) == 0.2989` returns false. It is safer to test whether two floating point values are *almost* equal, i.e. with regards to a tolerance value `tol`:

```
>> tol = 1/1000;
>> abs(T(1,1) - 0.2989) < tol
ans =
     1
```

Here's something you should probably read: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary)